# print out balance sheet after getting data from different database table

Tags: php, mysqli

[this image is showing 2 tables and output UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/656kB.png)

my code is as below

```
            //**********************  credit query  ***************************/
            $sql = 'SELECT *,sum(pl_amount) as sum_pl_amount FROM payments_log left join payments on payments_log.pl_order_no=payments.order_no WHERE pl_date LIKE "%'.$date.'%" group by pl_date order by pl_id';
            $qry = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
            while($cData = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry))
            {
                $creditData[] = $cData;
            }


            //**********************  debit query   ***************************/
            $query  = "SELECT *, sum(e_amount) as sum_e_amount FROM expenses WHERE e_date LIKE '%".$date."%' group by e_date order by e_date";
            $run    = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
            $cnt    = mysqli_num_rows($run);

            while($dData = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run))
            {
                $debitData[] = $dData;
            }


            //echo '<pre>';print_r($creditData);print_r($debitData);


            //********************  print data  ***************************/
            for($j=0;$j<$cnt;$j++)
            {
                $dateStr    = '';
                $creditAmt  = '';
                $debitAmt   = '';

                if(array_key_exists($j, $creditData) && array_key_exists($j, $debitData))
                {
                    if($creditData[$j]['pl_date'] === $debitData[$j]['e_date'])
                    {
                        $dateStr    = changeDateFormat('Y-m-d','d/m/Y',$creditData[$j]['pl_date']);
                        $creditAmt  = $creditData[$j]['sum_pl_amount'];
                        $debitAmt   = $debitData[$j]['sum_e_amount'];
                    }

                    if(array_key_exists($j, $creditData))
                    {
                        $dateStr    = changeDateFormat('Y-m-d','d/m/Y',$creditData[$j]['pl_date']);
                        $creditAmt  = $creditData[$j]['sum_pl_amount'];
                        $debitAmt   = '';
                    }

                    if(array_key_exists($j, $debitData))
                    {
                        $dateStr    = changeDateFormat('Y-m-d','d/m/Y',$debitData[$j]['e_date']);
                        $creditAmt  = '';
                        $debitAmt   = $debitData[$j]['sum_e_amount'];
                    }
                }

            ?>
                <tr role="row">
                  <td> <?php echo $i;?></td>
                  <td> <?php echo $dateStr;  ?></td>
                  <td> <?php echo $creditAmt;?></td>
                  <td> <?php echo $debitAmt; ?></td>
                </tr>
    <?php       $i++;
            }?>
```

I m trying to print out date wise monthly balance sheet which will shows credit and debit amount like above image

can anybody check my code and help me get desired output.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: DO you want to display records of matching dates in both tables, OR you need to display all records from both tables ordered by date?

Comment: Please take a look of image which I added.
what I want is :
if I have a record having both credit and debit on same day exp. table 24/05/2016 , then both data should be there.

if we have either credit or debit then only that data will show.